# concat two numbers in sas proc sql

Tags: sas

I have a table that has two numeric values called `year` and `month`. I would like to create a new table that has one value called `ym` which is just the concatenation of `year` and `month`. Here is an example:

```
proc sql;
create table test as 
select CONCAT(year, month) as ym from tbl;
run;
```

What is the `CONCAT` function that goes there?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

CAT, CATS, CATT, CATX all perform concatenation, as long as you're on 9.1.3 or later (and CATQ on 9.2 or later); CAT does basic concatenation, CATS concatenates and strips spaces, CATT trims, and CATX concatenates with a delimiter.

Typically CATS is the correct function to use for numbers, since by default numbers are put into a format with spaces (BEST12., so "3           " is 3).

```
proc sql;
create table test as 
select CATS(year, month) as ym from tbl;
run;
```

Comment: I always +1 answers using any of the CAT% functions ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As another option, you can concatenate with the `||` operator like `X1||X2` or even multiples at once like `X1||X2||X3||X4`

You can add `trim` or `left` like `TRIM(LEFT(X1))||TRIM(LEFT(X2))`

You can add delimeters like `TRIM(X1)||','||TRIM(X2)`

Comment: I get this: "ERROR: Concatenation (||) requires character operands." TRIM also seems to want characters to begin with.